# Is there a way to "save" the state of a modal, or allow a login without changing page?

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

I have a modal that allows the user to login through another provider with OpenID. The modal has 4 "stages", where the login is the 2nd stage. When they click on the button to log in, it redirects them off the page so they can log in. This, however, refreshes the page (since it changes pages) and the modal is gone (I made it go away once they log in).

I want it so they can log in through the modal through redirect without refreshing the page/modal (or another way). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: One approach might be to use `localStorage` to save the current state (data) in for example in JSON-format, then recreate the modal in the correct state when the user returns (even if the page refreshes). Would that be an option maybe?

Comment: localStorage or sessionStorage or encode your details in url while redirecting to another page.